# Possible security concern for embedding Qlik dashboard as an Iframe on a VF Page

Tags: single-sign-on, iframe, saml

I'm working on a use case to embed a Qlik dashboard on Salesforce . I understand that to achieve this one would have to setup SF as Identity Provider , configure connected app and SAML settings on Qlik and then embed the app url as an iFrame into a VF Page .

My question is -

1. Is this the correct approach ?
2. Is there any security concern for using iFrame to embed the dashboard? If yes then what would be an alternate approach?

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct approach ?

This may or may not be a correct approach. Other approaches may also be possible, depending on the capabilities of the system in question. For example, the site may use X-Frame-Options to deny embedding, or may use frame busting techniques to break out of an iframe and take over the top window. You'll need to check their documentation for what's allowed and what's not.

> Is there any security concern for using iFrame to embed the dashboard? If yes then what would be an alternate approach?

It's generally safe, especially for a commercial application, but if you have any reservations, make sure you [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) the iframe. This provides additional browser-enforced security options.